# How to check if a value is empty in Lua?

Tags: lua, conditional-statements

What is the proper way to make a conditional which checks of something is or is not empty in Lua? `if x == ""` and `f x ~= ""` does not seem to work.

Comment: Empty meaning, there is nothing typed in it.

Comment: You can't "type" values into variables. Can you give a more precise definition? Because a variable that holds the `""` string isn't "empty". It has a string. Namely `""`. Which is a valid string. And therefore not nothing.

Comment: Okay, then my meaning of empty is `""`.

Comment: Then in what way doesn't your code work? `x = ""; if x == "" then print("empty"); else print("not empty"); end` is valid Lua code. And it will always print "empty". Is your problem that it ceases to work when you don't have the `x = ""` part? Or, to put it another way, just because *you* think `""` means empty doesn't mean *Lua* does.

Comment: Provide us with some context; are you setting the value to `""` at any time? Are you reading the value from input? Is this a value returned by a library? It'll clarify to us what you mean by "empty" (a very subjective term) hence allowing us to help you more effectively.

Comment: I am using Lua inside ConTeXt. The value is empty, e.g., `\macro{}`.

Answer (score 17):

Lua is a **dynamically type-based language**.
Any variable can hold one of the following types: *nil*, *boolean*, *number*, *string*, *table*, *function*, *thread*, or *userdata*.
Any variable in a table (including `_G`, the table where globals reside) without a value gives a value of `nil` when indexed. When you set a table variable to `nil`, it essentially "undeclares" it (removing the entry from memory entirely).
When a `local` variable is declared, if it is not assigned immediately it is given a value of `nil`. Unlike table variable, when you set a `local` variable to `nil`, it does *not* "undeclare" it (it just has a value of `nil`).

In Lua, an empty string (`""`) is still a "value" - it's simply a string of size zero.

Comment: I think saying "_When you set a variable to nil, it essentially "undeclares" it_" is a bit inaccurate&mdash;`nil` is a true value except inside tables, so for instance, a local variable with a value `nil` still shadows variables in surrounding scopes...

Comment: You're absolutely right; that statement was aimed at table pairs, not at all variables in general. Answer's been modified to reflect this.

Comment: @snogglethorpe
`if nil then
 print( "nil is true")
else
 print( "nil is not true!")
end`
--> nil is not true!

Comment: @handle Heh... sorry, by "true value" I mean "real value", i.e. I was using "true" in the colloquial sense not in the Lua sense... ^^;

Comment: (I#m sorry, while this is a very old answer - I came here because it is root to a dupe. Reading the answer does not answer the question for me. Maybe the answer is technically hidden in it - for me as a nonprogrammer it talks about reasons & constraints and avoids a useful answer. Someone in the dupe was quick enough to post it there before closure. Just thought I could upvote here too)

Comment: This response does not answer the question

Answer (score 5):

I recently ran across this problem as well. LuaSQL was returning empty strings if a database value was 'blank' (not null). A hacky approach, but here's how I solved it:

```
if (string.len(x) >= 1) then
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to make an assumption that the OP means "how do you tell when a variable is unassigned".

Example:

```
local x
```

The variable x is "empty", it is initialized to "nil".  (Not the text "nil", but an enumerated value that indicates that the variable is unassigned.  In Lua that is defined as nil, in some other languages it is defined as NULL.)

Now assign x a value.
Example:

```
x=""
```

Now x is not nil.
Another example:

```
x=0
```

x is not nil.

Try running this code, it should make the situation clear to you.

```
local x
if x==nil then print("x is nil") end

x=0
if x==nil then print( "This line won't be written") end

x=""
if x==nil then print( "and this line won't be written") end
```

The first *if* statement will evaulate to true and the print statement will be called.  The 2nd and 3rd *if* statements are false and the print statements will not be executed.

In conclusion, use "==nil" to check to see if a variable is "empty" (which is more properly said "nil").

Answer (score 1):

You probably have spaces, newlines or other non-visible characters in your string. So you think it is "empty", but it isn't. This typically happens when you are taking input from the user, and has to type "enter" to finish - the "enter" ends up in the string.

What you need is a function that tells you whether the string is "blank" - either empty, or a list of spaces/tabs/newlines. Here's one way to do it:

```
function isBlank(x)
  return not not tostring(x):find("^%s*$")
end
```

Usage:

```
if isBlank(x) then
  -- ...
end
```

Comment: thats quite inefficient; `not not string.find(x,"^%s*$")`

Comment: Well, your version is definitively (once you include the ommited tostring call). I'm not so sure it is significantly faster. Why do you think that?

Comment: `string.gsub` would allocate a lot of memory for that operation (a new string that's resized several times, one or two buffers for replacements) compared to `string.find`.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking in term of speed execution, not memory. I've updated my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: not not? Am I missing something or is this just a typo. Remove "not not" and it still works yet is much easier to read.

Comment: `not not` is a common idiom which means "transform into a boolean" in Lua. I don't use it often, but since the OP seems to be new to Lua, I figured he'd be less confused by a function that returns either `true` or `false`. Besides, `string.find` returns multiple values, which might have some side effects and catch you off-guard when you're new to the language. `not not` takes care of all that.

Comment: Isn't <<not  tostring(x):find('%S')>> have the same meaning?

Comment: local xd = "     "
Function is named isBlank which means that for xd it should return true.
not tostring(x):find("^%s*$") would return false for an empty string.

That's why there is not not. That is what the answerer was refering to,
while find returns different values by default.